# Send email alert when opportunity stage equals 'closed lost'

Tags: email, workflow, email-template, email-alert, notification

I have created an email alert, an email template and a workflow.

The workflow is Active, with the following rule (for testing):

> Opportunity: Stage EQUALS Closed Lost

Evaluation criteria:

> Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited

Email template is 'available for use'.
I have sent a test email and I receive the email.

Email Alert details:
[image]

**EDIT**:
[image]

Workflow rule:
[image]

When I change the status of an opportunity to 'Closed Lost' I don't receive an email alert. Have I missed something really obvious?

Comment: Is "Closed Lost" a literal and exact value you have in your `Stagename` picklist? Do you have email deliverability set to "All Emails" in the org you're testing this in?

Comment: @DerekF yes - "Closed Lost" is the exact value. Deliverability is set to All email. Please see screenshot within Edit above

Comment: it says "this alert is currently not used by any rules" on the first image.  are you actually using it?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi it looks like that is the issue. How can I make the email alert use the rule? ...I have added a screenshot of the workflow rule for info.

Comment: @h3110 I have added details as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your issue is that you have created the email alert, but it is not used in any workflow rule. You need to add it to the field update as an immediate action.

On your third screen click edit  and follow steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workflow_immediate_actions.htm&type=5):

> Open a workflow rule.
>
> In the Immediate Workflow Actions section, click Add Workflow Action.
>
> Select one of the options to create an action or select an existing one.

Click "Add Workflow Action" and "Select Existing Action" and select your "Alert/notification when...." as "Email Alert"

---

In general, consider using Flows, as workflows and process builders are subject to retirement in a year or so by salesforce.